# javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when there is trailing slash at the end of the url

Tags: javascript, php, html, nginx

I have all html of my site in `index.php`.
what I am doing is whenever someone clicks on blog button. I am using pushState to change the url and show/hide different section based on the url

`history.pushState({}, '', '/blog/');`

and on nginx server what I did is if any page reload happens load the index.php page.

so if someone reload the page from `/blog/` at initial state the index page will load and on javascript I am handing the url like this

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
  case '/blog':
    // show blog page
    showSection(blogSection, 'Blog');
    break;
```

everything works as expected if I remove the trailing slash when pushState().
But I need to keep the trailing slash. how can I achieve this?

Comment: Tried cascading `case` statements, eg `case '/blog': case '/blog/': ...`? Or perhaps trim the trailing `/` from the `switch` candidate... `switch (window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, ""))`

Comment: I think the error is not related to switch statements. cause, if I completely remove the switch statement, the error persists.

Comment: Could you please explain what the problem is then... what happens? Are there any errors reported anywhere (nginx / PHP logs, browser console, etc)? What does your `try_files` look like?

Comment: problem is in my console I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`
this is try files `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php`

Comment: everything works as expected before I give trailing slash to history.pushState url

before: history.pushState({}, '', '/blog');

after: history.pushState({}, '', '/blog/');

Comment: Ah, what do your `<script>` tags look like? You're probably using relative URLs and `script.js` relative to `/blog/` is `/blog/script.js` which probably doesn't exist so nginx is serving up your `index.php` file. You want `<script src="/script.js">` (absolute paths)

Comment: `<script src="./assets/js/core/app.js"></script>`  nginx is serving php file  and I expect this. this is not an issue. issue is the error of the console, I thing problem occurs on javascript end.

Comment: `./` should just be `/`, ie `src="/assets/js/core/app.js"`. The `.` means it's relative to the current URL which for `/blog` is `/` whereas for `/blog/` it's `/blog/`. The problem is that nginx will serve your `index.php` file for `/blog/assets/js/core/app.js` which as I'm sure you're aware, is not JavaScript

Comment: yah. It solved the issue. :)